# React PrivateRoute is caught in a Route loop

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I have a `PrivateRoute` component that protects any route requiring a valid login in the app. I have a route called `Spec.tsx` that is called from `App.tsx`. `PrivateRoute` will spit you out on the `Login` page if you're not logged in, which is great. And `Login` will send you directly to the `Home` page if you **are** logged in. Also great.

Right now, I'm caught in a loop where when I go to `Spec`, the app thinks I'm not logged in, and sends me to `Login`, which **does** think I'm logged in, and so sends me back to `Home`. `currentUser` is always calculated the same was, like `const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);`

When I log the `currentUser` in `PrivateRoute` as I navigate to `/spec/:id` it says `null` once, and then gives the correct answer 3 more times. I suspect the `null` causes me to get booted to `Login` and then `currentUser` must be assigned correctly as I'm sent back to `Home` immediately. I don't even ever get to `Spec.tsx`, nothing I try to log there gets logged. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
//In App.tsx
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/spec/:id" render={() => (
            <Spec isEdit={true}/>
          )}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
```

```
//PrivateRoute.tsx
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../Util/Auth";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }: any) => {
  const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(currentUser)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(routeProps: any) =>
        !!currentUser ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute
```

```
//Login.tsx
const Login = ({ history }: any) => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (currentUser) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

  return (
    //My JSX
  )
```

My Auth provider is below, which handles all changes to `currentUser`

```
//Auth.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createNewUser } from "../Models/User";
import app from "./firebase";

const initialUser: any = null;

export const AuthContext = React.createContext(initialUser);

export const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<any>(null);
  const [currentDBUser, setCurrentDBUser] = useState<any>(null);
  const [pending, setPending] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [pending2, setPending2] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Auth user
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setPending(false)
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });
    //Grab database data for user
    async function fetchData() {
      if (currentUser && !currentDBUser && pending2) {
        const newUser: User = {fbUser: currentUser.uid, email: currentUser.email}
        const userDBObject = await createNewUser(newUser);
        if (userDBObject) {
          setCurrentDBUser(userDBObject);
          setPending2(false);
        }
      }
    }
    if (pending2) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [currentUser, currentDBUser, pending2]);

  if (pending) {
    return <>Loading...</>
  }

  return (
  <AuthContext.Provider value= {{ currentUser, currentDBUser }}>
    { children }
  </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: when and where do you change `currentUser`?

Comment: I've added it to the question at the end, thanks